# Name Error with will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, nameerror

I'm trying to use will_paginate and have done everything listed in the [github](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) installation/use instructions, but I'm getting a NameError when I try to load the page:

```
uninitialized constant BooksController::Books
```

In my Gemfile I have:

```
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'
```

In my controller I have:

```
def index
        #paginate books, have 10 per page
        @books = Books.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10
    end
```

And in my index.html.erb, I have added:

```
<%= will_paginate @books %>
```

Has anyone encountered this? I've run bundle install, and the gem appeared to be installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  like this `@books = Book.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 10`

Model name should not be **plurals**